# Erro no namespace quando crio "Resource Dictionary ..." dentro de uma pasta

Tags: wpf, namespace, dicionário

Num projeto vazio (teste - WPF Application) testo dois cenários.

**Cenário 1**

- Botão direito sobre o projeto
- Add
- Resource Dictionary ...
  Obtenho o seguinte:

```html
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:teste">
    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Cenário 2**

- Botão direito sobre o projeto
- Add
- New Folder (pasta)
- Botão direito sobre a "pasta"
- Add
- Resource Dictionary ...

Obtenho:

```html
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:teste.pasta">
    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Neste segundo cenário, "clr-namespace:teste.pasta" contém um ondulado azul que indica o erro "Undefined CLR-Namespace. ..."

O que está mal aqui?

Answer (score 0):

Por padrão, o Visual Studio cria o namespace das entidades baseando-se na estrutura das pastas do local onde a entidade é criada, seguindo o padrão `[namespace padrão do projeto].[Pasta].[Subpasta]` e assim sucessivamente.

Quando você cria um dicionário, o *VS* adiciona uma referência ao *namespace* "local" utilizando o mesmo padrão, para facilitar a utilização de classes desse *namespace*. Entretanto, o *namespace* `teste.pasta` não é encontrado, pois não possui nenhuma entidade declarada.

Um jeito fácil de corrigir é apagando o `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:teste.pasta"` do dicionário. Se você pretende declarar outra entidade nesse mesmo *namespace* (por exemplo criando uma classe dentro dessa pasta), esse problema irá sumir automaticamente, uma vez que o *namespace* passará a existir.